# How do I send a message when bot.wait_for reaches time limit?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to send a message after bot.wait_for time limit reaches.
Here's my code:

```py
 msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=10)
 if msg is None:
     await ctx.send('Apparently you ran out of time...')
```

Unfortunately the message is not sent.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), the timeout rises the [*asyncio.TimeoutError*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.TimeoutError) exception.

So in your case, I just would catch that exception and send the respective message.